# Не получается обмен значений в списках

Tags: python, list, swap

Обмен одиночных переменных по типу: `a,b = b,a` получается хорошо,но вот в списках при таком же выражение, элемент `а` заменяет элемент `b`.
Возможно ли сделать такой обмен,в исходном списке?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример входного списка и какой результат вы хотите получить.

Comment: Сейчас я практикуюсь с сортировкой вставкой,и таким образом хотел поменять местами числа 
`a = [8,3,7]
sort = 0

for i in range(len(a)):
    x = min(a[sort:])
    a[i],x = x,a[i]
    sort+=1
`

Comment: @PythonNewbie надо научиться отличать элемент списка от **значения** элемента списка.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev и все же,возможно ли сделать так?

Comment: @PythonNewbie в моём ответе показано как можно сделать.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1, 2]
x[0], x[1] = x[1], x[0]
```